# How can I prevent iPad Multitasking Gesture from locking mobile web app?

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-website, multitasking-gestures, ios-standalone-mode

If I have a mobile web app (website with meta tag `name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"`) and save it to the homescreen to create the "app"... then open the app and use the four finger swipe to switch applications and switch back to the mobile web app... it will bring me back, but the app is completely locked/frozen/disabled.

Is there any way to make it so the app doesn't get locked when swiping away and back to it? If not, I suppose it would be better to restart the app than bring up a frozen screen.. so would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

[Restarting](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_reset_ios_apps) the app is easy.

I dont know of any programatic way to disable the 4-finger swipe. I believe you go to settings> general> Multitasking gestures and turn them off.

Comment: not really looking to turn it off, but rather make it work as gracefully as possible (not freezing the app)

Comment: <html>
     <head>
     <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
     </head>
     <body>
     <a href="#" />test link</a>
     </body>
     </html>

even just this will show the issue... if you open this html in safari and click "add to home screen" and then open from homescreen... then swipe 4 fingers to leave and come back to it... you wont even be able to click the link

Comment: easier to see with a select menu than the link: <html> <head> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> </head> <body><select><option>test1</option><option>test2</option></select> </body> </html>

Comment: yes I see your problem, unfortunately I dont have a solution. This seems to be an iOS bug. It might get fixed in their incremental releases. But dont rely on it.

Comment: Indeed, I fought with this problem the whole day (along with some cache problems always with iPad) and I saw that this one is just not possible. Luckily many people that owns apple stuff don't know the 4 finger swipe gesture

Comment: cool, if something or someone's answer(s) have helped you in any way please contribute back to the site by upvoting...

Comment: FWIW: Our app runs into this in older versions of iOS, but no longer sees it on iOS 6.1.3